# Vim auto wrap not working - the way I think it is supposed to

Tags: vim, iterm

I am curious as to whether or not I am understanding how wrapping works in Vim. I have my textwidth set to 80 but yet when I type, and continue to type, it goes over that mark and does not wrap until I hit return. When this happens I then have to go and hit delete to go back to that line I was working on and continue to type. Is there a setting that prevents this from happening?

I have created a quick cast video showing what happens that might be of use for you to see where the issue is happening: http://quick.as/pl0sd2vg

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: have you tried just typing your text till the paragraph end, then pressing `ESC`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `formatoptions` is only set to `r` and not `t`.

From `help fo-table`:

> t Auto-wrap text using textwidth
>
> r Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
>      in Insert mode.

To check your current format options, run `:set fo?`
It should include `t`, e.g., mine is `formatoptions=tcroql`.
If it doesn't include the `t` option, add it using `set fo+=t`.

(I hope I understood your question correctly, I couldn't view your video from my current location.)

Comment: Thank you for the help and showing me the `help fo-table`